# I can't understand why does my pthread freeze

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I was trying to create a thread safe queue, but something went wrong. I can't understand why does my thread freeze.
Expected: 1 2 3, but i get nothing (everything just freezes)

I guess the problem is misuse of condition variable in front (pop) and get (peek) methods, but I can't find my mistake.
Could you please point out my mistake and explain what the mistake is?

```
template<class T>
class SafeQueue {
private:
    std::queue<T> _data;
    pthread_mutex_t _mutex;
    pthread_cond_t _condition;
public:
    SafeQueue();
    ~SafeQueue();
    void push(const T &x);
    T front();
    bool peek(T &x);
    bool get(T &x);
};

template<class T>
SafeQueue<T>::SafeQueue(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&_condition, NULL);
}

template<class T>
SafeQueue<T>::~SafeQueue(){
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&_mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&_condition);
}

template<class T>
void SafeQueue<T>::push(const T &x){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    _data.push(x);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
}

template<class T>
T SafeQueue<T>::front(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    T temp;
    while(!get(temp)){
        pthread_cond_wait(&_condition, &_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    return temp;
}

template<class T>
bool SafeQueue<T>::get(T &x){
    bool result = false;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    if(!_data.empty()){
        result = true;
        x = _data.front();
        pthread_cond_signal(&_condition);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    return result;
}

template<class T>
void SafeQueue<T>::pop(){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    T temp;
    while(!peek(temp)){
        pthread_cond_wait(&_condition, &_mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
}

template<class T>
bool SafeQueue<T>::peek(T &x){
    bool result = false;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
    if(!_data.empty()){
        result = true;
        x = _data.front();
        _data.pop();
        pthread_cond_signal(&_condition);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
    return result;
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(){
    SafeQueue<int> q;
    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);
    q.push(3);
    cout << q.front() << endl; q.pop();
    cout << q.front() << endl; q.pop();
    cout << q.front() << endl; q.pop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show the code with the thread that freezes?

Comment: @Enkidu [Edit] your question to add additional information when it's requested. Don't do that in comments. You're supposed to post a [mcve].

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number 
added it in the question

Comment: what output do you get, what output did you expect?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
Expected: 1 2 3
I get: nothing (everything just freezes)

Comment: how about adding that to the question too? Please read about [mcve]. The question should contain everything necessary to know what exactly the issue is and to reprouce it

Comment: Your code can't compile: error: 'class SafeQueue<int>' has no member named 'pop'

Comment: In the code shown you lock the mutex recursively in `front` and then `get` but you don't appear to be using a recursive mutex (with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` attribute).  That will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Laci 
added the required methods to the question description

Comment: now you added a definition for `pop` but it is not declared in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your `front` :

> ```
> template<class T>
> T SafeQueue<T>::front(){
>     pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
>     T temp;
>     while(!get(temp)){
>         pthread_cond_wait(&_condition, &_mutex);
>     }
>     pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
>     return temp;
> }
> ```

It locks the mutex, does some stuff, releases the mutex. As part of "some stuff" it calls `get(temp)`.

Your `get` is:

> ```
> template<class T>
> bool SafeQueue<T>::get(T &x){
>     bool result = false;
>     pthread_mutex_lock(&_mutex);
>     if(!_data.empty()){
>         result = true;
>         x = _data.front();
>         pthread_cond_signal(&_condition);
>     }
>     pthread_mutex_unlock(&_mutex);
>     return result;
> }
> ```

It tries to lock the mutex....

From the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock):

> If the mutex is already locked, the calling thread shall block until the mutex becomes available.

The mutex never becomes available, because it is locked in the caller (`front`) and will only be released when `get` returns, but `get` does never return.

One way to avoid such deadlock is to use private methods that do the actual work but don't use the mutex. Only lock the mutex in public methods. Then you only need to make sure to never call a public method from another public method. Alternatively use a recursive mutex.

In any case I suggest you to use `std::thread` and its relatives (`std::mutex` and others).

Comment: Thank you for your help! After the fixes everything started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaked, you're locking the mutex in the Front() func and then inside it you call get(temp) which is attempting to lock again, which should not be possible.